# Heroku error H10 - (App crashed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, rubygems

I have a RoR app working on my local computer, but when I send it 
to heroku, it crashes. The error log gives an error H10 & says:

```
    $ heroku logs




2011-04-05T10:37:32-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-04-05T10:37:39-07:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from created to starting

2011-04-05T10:37:44-07:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from starting to up
2011-04-05T10:37:48-07:00 heroku[rake.2]: State changed from up to complete
2011-04-05T10:38:29-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 94.67.108.192 | 795 |
http | 503
2011-04-05T17:38:30+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T17:40:24+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/login dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T17:40:25+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T17:40:36+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/pages/api dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T10:40:37-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /pages/api HTTP/1.1 | 94.67.108.192
 | 796 | http | 503
2011-04-05T17:40:37+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T10:47:31-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-04-05T10:47:31-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/ruby
gems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem oauth (>= 0.3.5)
(Gem::LoadError)
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/controllers/comments_contr
oller.rb:1
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in `require_or_load'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in `depend_on'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.5
/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in `require_dependency'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:414:in `load_application_classes'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:413:in `each'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:413:in `load_application_classes'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:411:in `each'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:411:in `load_application_classes'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:197:in `process'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:113:in `send'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/ini
tializer.rb:113:in `run'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:9
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1
.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge
ms/thin-1.2.6/lib/rack/adapter/rails.rb:42:in `load_application'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-04-05T10:47:39-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-04-05T10:57:34-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-04-05T10:57:34-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge
ms/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `map'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:18
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge
ms/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge
ms/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11:in `
new'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:11
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge
ms/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/ge
ms/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `n
ew'
2011-04-05T10:57:39-07:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-04-05T10:57:40-07:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-04-05T18:01:44+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T18:01:44+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T11:01:45-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 94.67.108.1
92 | 796 | http | 503
2011-04-05T11:07:13-07:00 heroku[rake.3]: State changed from created to starting

2011-04-05T11:07:19-07:00 heroku[rake.3]: State changed from starting to up
2011-04-05T11:07:21-07:00 heroku[rake.3]: State changed from up to complete
2011-04-05T18:07:43+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T11:07:44-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 94.67.108.192 | 795 |
http | 503
2011-04-05T18:07:44+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET vivid-l
ight-27.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-04-05T11:07:44-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 | 94.67.108.1
92 | 796 | http | 503
```

Has anyone had this before, and know what might be causing the 
problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have anything from before that?

Comment: i had this: 2011-04-05T10:37:09-07:00 app[web.1]: Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem. Please `gem i
nstall -v=2.3.5 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environm
ent.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VER
SION to use the latest version installed.

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the log:

```
gems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem oauth (>= 0.3.5)
```

You're probably using rails 2.3, and need to add oauth to your .gems file.

Comment: I am using twitter gem that includes oauth gem.

Comment: I would explicitly add it to your .gems file. That is the problem.

Comment: just to make sure, you added, you committed, and you pushed to heroku?

Comment: i commited..it's ok! but the problem is the rack i guess!

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved!

Because Rails 2.3.5 and older are incompatible with Rack 1.1.0 my application failed to start.
The twitter gem dependencies conflicted with rack so i specified the --ignore-dependencies flag on .gems to ignore Rack and added the other dependencies to .gems manual.

they are:

```
oauth --version 0.3.5
mash --version 0.0.3 --ignore-dependencies
hoe --version 1.5.1
httparty --version 0.4.3
```

EVERYTHING WORKS FINE!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku gem install v=2.3.5 rails
```

Comment: comment out rails version in environment.rb